What is the relationship between a fluid vortex's expansion rate and its kinematic viscosity?
I've read through research papers with very specific radius formulas pertaining to 2D fluid vortexes, such as confined rotation with variations in pressure and density ($\rho(r,t)$ and $p(r,t)$), inviscid Eulerian forms, and summation notation of particles. I'm looking for a radius function, $R(t)$, for an incompressible, irrotational vortex without boundary conditions (like the inner surface of a coffee mug) that, given some kinematic viscosity, $\nu$, the vortex can freely expand forever. The units of $\nu$ is in $m^2/s$, and the radius $R(t)$ is in meters, $m$. Would a radial velocity differential equation look something like this? $$ \frac{\mathrm{d} R}{\mathrm{d} t}=\frac{\nu }{R}\left [ \frac{m^2}{s}\frac{1}{m} \right ]$$

Starting from incompressible Navier$-$Stokes equations, assuming a 2D flow field
$$\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{r}, t) = u_{\theta}(r, t) \boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}} \ ,$$
the momentum equation becomes
$$\begin{aligned}
 r&: -\frac{u_{\theta}^2}{r} + \frac{1}{\rho} \partial_r P = 0 \\
 \theta&: \partial_t u_{\theta} - \nu \partial_r\left( \frac{1}{r} \partial_r (r u_{\theta}) \right) = 0 \ ,
\end{aligned}$$
while the incompressibility constraint is an identity. The azimuthal component of the momentum equation is a diffusion equation in a axial symmetric domain, while the radial component can be used to evaluate the pressure field, once the velocity field is known.
For the actual solution of the problem, proper initial conditions for $u_{\theta}(r, 0)$ and boundary conditions are required.
Once you've evaluated $u_\theta(r,t)$ you could evaluate the radius of the vortex, setting a threshold on the vorticity or on a desired parameter of the velocity field.

Wow! This was very helpful deriving the pressure field I needed, but since R(t) is in the azimuthal velocity component, $u_\theta$ (a component I already know), there are no initial conditions for either momentum equation components that seem to allow me to isolate R(t) except for u(0,t) rather than u(r,0). I have the full equation on another post here.
